# Domain name suggestions

Tags: discussion, beta-essentials

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name apple.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

List them off, try to only put one in each answer though instead of a list of ten. This allows people to upvote individual answers instead of a block.

Answer (score 39):

## AskDifferent.com

(It's currently available.)

Comment: A brilliant suggestion!

Comment: Great name!  Beautiful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this represents the first and last time I'll be referred to as being either brilliant or beautiful, but I'll take it all the same.

Comment: Someone has this now gents, unless it's one of you it's off the table.

Comment: I think it's being held for this purpose by SE.

Comment: Yes, I snagged it for this purpose.

Comment: @Robert: I was thinking of doing the same, but didn't want to snafu the thing if it was chosen. Much thanks!

Comment: Old-time apple users can maybe somehow relate to this, but it took me a while to understand why it is so :-(

Comment: "Ask Different" isn't even proper English!! English is my fourth foreign language and even I can see it's plain wrong. Is "Different" a person? Did you mean "Ask *differently*"? Do people really want a title that sounds like we can't even get basic grammar right?

Answer (score 8):

http://apple.stackexchange.com

seems perfectly acceptable to me.

Answer (score 6):

## MacOverflow.com

It rhymes with Stack Overflow!

Comment: Why put *overflow* everywhere ?

Comment: I don't think it needs Overflow in the name

Comment: @Adam: are we suffering from an overflow of overflows?

Answer (score 3):

### askaboutapple.com

available

Answer (score 2):

## TalkingApples.com

Available

Maybe to similar to talkingapple.com, which is taken.

Answer (score 0):

### finelytunedmagic.com

available

Answer (score 0):

## applequeries.com

available

Answer (score 0):

### infinitelyloop.com

as courtesy to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Loop_(street).

As variation: infinitelylooping.com
It is taken but seems not used.

Sadly... InfiniteLoop.com is already taken

Answer (score -2):

## AisForAnswer.com

available

From an Apple II ad.

[image]

http://www.wired.com/gadgets/mac/multimedia/2006/04/appleads?slide=2&slideView=8

Answer (score -3):

I can donate http://coverflowexchange.com/