# Official Site Title

Tags: design

Hi all. I have some exciting news to share. A design for the official Apple.se site is in the works!

I need to ask the community what the final text in the header logo should be. Right now it's just "Apple." I feel it's a bit incomplete. Would "Apple Q&A" make more sense?

I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I have some suggestion for accepted answer put green apple on it in your design :D

Comment: woot!  great news!

Comment: Just curious, how many sites are scheduled to launch before us?

Comment: @kyle 1 or 2. However we re-evalute the stats of each Beta site every week, so the launch order is subject to change.

Comment: @Dori, thanks! I have seen the logo thread. I think since Apple dropped the rainbow colors in 1998, it may not reflect of Apple of today. Also for SE site logos, we don't need to make it look like the SE logo. I think the ⌘ symbol may be more fitting. It has an interesting backstory too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key#The_origin_of_.22.E2.8C.98.22

Comment: @Dori What would be bad about using ⌘? I don't think people are going to refer to it by name, so it shouldn't matter if there are multiple names for it.

Comment: @dori but hasn't the rainbow apple icon been obsolete for a solid decade now? Also, we're looking for something people in that community will recognize, like a secret handshake. The words "Stack Overflow", for example, are meaningless to the 99.9% of people who aren't programmers.

Comment: @dori: I've stayed out of this debate since my suggestion of ⌘ until now, but the reason why I didn't vote for the rainbow logo is for exactly the first reason that @Jeff states. I love my collection of OS 9 and earlier Macs, but those days are long gone. The reason why I suggested ⌘ is because it has been on every Mac since the first, the Mac is a cornerstone of Apple's product line (we can't develop for the iOS properly without a Mac), and it is still on the keyboard today; ⌘ has outlasted the rainbow-themed logo.

Comment: Oops, it seems I did vote for a rainbow logo, the one currently with four votes. Personally, I'm fine with whatever the community decides here. All of the designs are great so far (Programmers.SE is my current favorite of the sites I visit), so I'm sure whatever is done will look just fine.

Comment: After having thought of this a bit more, I have to say I'm stumped.  Not to state the plainly obvious, if we use , we will incur the wrath of Apple's legal eagles. If we use the spectrum, probably not so much, but I don't think it really says "Apple" like it used to; the logo has always been really about the silhouette, I've always thought. Also, I thought one of the requirements was to have something that would work in one color as well, and in that case the spectrum simply won't work.

Comment: If memory serves ⌘ has outlasted every icon in Apple's existence, and has only recently *not* been included in Apple products on such a large scale. I'm sure if used in a context with Apple, we still run the same low risk, but still a risk, as the spectrum. I don't recall there being other "branded" SE site like this one, but I'd be curious to know how this scenario has been handled if there is one.

Comment: I do not think, however, that having ⌘ as the logo will cause the site to narrow its focus to just the Macintosh line, especially if we use "Apple" somewhere in the *by-line* for the site (i.e., "Ask Different: Apple Q&A For The Rest Of Us" (hey, I kind of like that)), then that would fall into the fair use clause of copyright, and it makes it clear to all newcomers that this is for Apple questions and not just Macs (though I think that if we did actually narrow the focus people would ask whatever they wanted anyway).

Comment: @Dori: It seems to me that the crux of the problem is that there are no longer really any icons in the Apple "iconosphere" that are ① universal to all products outside of  ② that also make sense for a Q&A site and ③ won't get us into possible legal mires. There are odd bits like System Preferences and Apple applications like iTunes that reach across the two OSes, but that's it. I don't think ⌘ is perfect either, but we have little else to go on. As for the downvoting, you really ought to consider the source (when you can) in that particular case. That is a great cheat sheet.

Comment: @Dori: One more thing, the spectrum logo I did vote for in the other thread was the one that made a whole icon as opposed to stripes (the one that's most popular) solely for the reason that in one color, the striped one would look exactly like the SE family logo, and adding in the  to compensate for that is out of the question (I think we would both agree).

Comment: This is why I stopped being a graphic designer. Programming is so much easier than this!

Comment: @Dori: reading this thread I was thinking of the preferences gears as well...

Comment: @dori: also, try not to take it personal, you also got **8** upvotes for that post including mine :)  everyone isn't always going to agree or even be nice, but it is the internet after all... that parts probably never going to change :)  At least you don't have an entire meta post dedicated to what a jerk you are like I do.

Comment: @Dori and others, I've enjoyed this debate. I think looking at the site design as a whole package, it needs to emote and reflect the theme of the site. The level of graphical details depends on the site's nature. Gaming has more, and Statistics has less. I try to find that fine balance. I want new users who come to the site to get "this is an Apple" site right away and veteran users enjoy the design as they provide valuable content. The logo is only part of this whole package. We all agree that we can't use , even a variation of it may get us in legal trouble. that's why I think ⌘ is [...]

Comment: [...] the next most recognizable symbol. Speaking of the design, occasionally I ask my respected designer friends to help out. The English site turned out great. For the Apple site, I've asked Mike Rundle of http://flyosity.com I feel he's more qualified to do the site than I. We talked about the creative direction, we both agreed it needs to reflect the Apple theme clearly, though may not explicitly copy all the Apple design elements. I'm very confident that he'll come up with a great design. I'll post it as soon as I receive it.

Comment: @Jin,@Dori,@Phillip: i posted my horrid idea over on the logo thread, try not to be too harsh :)

Comment: "I've asked Mike Rundle of flyosity.com". That's *awesome*.

Comment: @Jin Any updates?

Comment: @Kyle I will receive the design after the New Year, aiming to launch the site first week of Jan.

Comment: @Jin Great, looking forward to it. I saw the Unix site design and was getting a little jealous ;)

Comment: @Jin I hate to keep bugging you, but the first week in Jan is almost over. Has there been a delay?

Comment: @Kyle bug me anytime! :) I talked to the designer yesterday. he's fine tuning some last min changes will have the design for me tomorrow. I'll post it as soon as I get it.

Comment: @Jin Thanks for the update - I was going a little stir-crazy checking Meta for updates :)

Comment: @kyle I'm just as anxious as you are

Comment: @kyle btw, have you used SE tagset? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/ setup tag keywords and sites, so you can keep track of things without visiting the site.

Comment: @Jin I have, but one of the things I was checking was to see when the last time you or Mike visited Meta.Apple :)

Comment: @Jin Just FYI, there's a [feature request for a chat info box on the front page](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253/chat-status-on-landing-page-of-apple-se). Any chance you can squeeze it in?

Comment: @Jin: I'm not not an admin, but I'm anxious to see the site design. Any word on this?

Comment: @Philip A few days ago I heard that Jin had received the design and was working with the designer making a few changes. Hopefully this means that the design is imminent. However, I do share your anxiousness - it's now been over a month since this topic was posted.

Comment: @Kyle: Thanks for the update. Cheers

Comment: @Kyle, @Philip I have received the designs from Mike. I'm making some last round of tweaks before I present them to you. Should be in the next couple days. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I can't see where it originated, but the current tagline *Answers for your Apple questions* works very nicely for me. In general I hate taglines, but with the pleasantly short simple title **Ask Different** it works very well.

Comment: Amazing that people back in 2011 already thought the "Think Different" ad campaign was a bit obscure and long in the tooth (discontinued in 2002). Here in 2021 it seems borderline ridiculous to base the name of the site on an ad campaign nearly 20 years out of date.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to being too short, just calling our site "Apple" would probably result in some trademark issues. "Apple Q&A" might work, but I have to say that I did like the [top domain name suggestion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/domain-name-suggestions/24#24) "Ask Different".

Comment: I like "Ask Different" a lot, maybe have a tagline to go with it "There's an answer for that."

Comment: or title: "Apple Q&A" tagline: "There's an answer for that."

Comment: My suggestion would be to title the site 'Apple Q&A' and the tagline to be 'Ask Different' because I really like that line.

Answer (score 6):

We could make a play on the ubiquitous `Help` menu...

> Apple Help: There's an answer for
>   that.

Answer (score 6):

**Ask**Apple

Much better than the only somewhat related current title. The chiefly title is like the AskUbuntu site being called AskPerfection.

**Ask**Apple means the user knows exactly what the site is about straight away. And it fits better with existing stackexchange sites (AskUbuntu) and also stackexchange sites haven't really changed their title when going out of beta. 
Also the URL of the site matches the title much more than currently. Now it's like if Google changed their name but didn't change any of the domain names.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, one more idea I just came up with:

***Ask Different: Apple Q&A For The Rest Of Us***

It uses the favored URL, it uses "Apple" to make it clear the intent for the site in a place that would most likely fall under fair use, and it might look actually good on a t-shirt (but not as a tattoo).

Comment: I like this one best :)

Comment: Ooh. Well "Think Different" was discontinued in 2002, soon 9 years gone. See? We can't win here. Aaigh!

Answer (score 4):

I'm mostly neutral on this topic, but I would like to see the word 'Apple' somewhere in there.  There are many forums and websites that in their site headlines use  mac, iphone, ipad, apple, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe try to find a combination of all of the above.

Title: Apple Q&A

Tagline: ask different, there’s an answer for that.

or if we switch…

Title: Ask Different

Tag: There’s an answer for that Apple

something like that to satisfy both Apple wanters and tagliners only :)

Comment: Could work, but it seems like a mouthful

Comment: +1 for the first Title and Tag

Answer (score 3):

Cider Press: Bringing answers to your Apple hardware and software questions. No pulp added.

Answer (score 2):

I think just use Apple better for your design but you are right maybe it's not complete

Answer (score 2):

how about something like "The Apple Core"?