# Why is this site called "ask different"?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask Different, really? Surely Ask Apple](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/ask-different-really-surely-ask-apple)

I'm using a Mac right now to post this. And I'm not "different".

So why is this site called "Ask Different"?  In my opinion, it kind of sounds like you think Mac users are somehow "different", and this is alienating, in a way.

Plus what if the Mac user market shot up to 25% over a few years, for some weird reason?  Would we be "asking different" then, or "asking mainstream?"

I just don't think it's nice to call Mac users "Different".  Different from what? The mainstream?  Do you have to highlight it this way?  May be viewed as *marginally* offensive.

Comment: When someone declare itself as different, different=cool. When someone is considered by others as different, different may = alienating. So even the name is bad idea, there is zero alienating or offensive here.

Answer (score 11):

Ask Different is a play on the [Think Different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different) ad campaign that Apple ran in the '90s.

[image]

The Ask part just represents one of the site's core functions, asking.

The goal is in no way to label Apple users as somehow different; it's just a bit of nostalgia.

Comment: Just says that we want people who used computers in the 90s - iPad and iPhone users have no concept of Apple users like that

Comment: And I guess in this case it's acceptable to follow Apples poor grammar.  It **really** should be __**differently**__ ;}