# Why is this site's URL not the same as its name?

Tags: discussion, site-name

I have seen both [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/why-is-this-site-called-ask-different) and [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/ask-different-really-surely-ask-apple), and I am asking "the other side of the coin", in a way. What I was wondering is: why didn't we make the play on the Think Different campaign in the URL as well as in the site? It is strange to have a site called AskDifferent whose URL is apple.stackexchange.com… Why not askdifferent.com? After all, SO has stackoverflow.com, not .stackexchange.com, and same goes for AskUbuntu's askubuntu.com…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll hazard some thought as I was around when this was discussed with the moderators at that moment in time. I have speculation and opinions, but they are just that other than links to other posts.

---

The people that run the site registered http://askdifferent.com and point it to the name apple.stackexchange.com and the why is for them to answer. I think it had to do with not setting more precedent in making a custom name other than the original trilogy or a preference to market/brand things consistently for web market share numbers or appearances in building the reputation of the network. Having a custom domain necessarily weakens the link to the branding of the company and some process or some one made that call a while back.

The community has voted pretty overwhelmingly to have things the other way around - have the site served out of a custom name and have requests from the apple.stackexchange.com resolve to the custom name, but those are just internet votes and not anyone that has actual authority to make any change.

- [Domain name suggestions](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/domain-name-suggestions/24#24)

Answer (score 2):

This is covered (for all SE sites) in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).

I believe SO, SU, AskUbuntu, and any others have those names purely for historical reasons. SO because it's SO; I *think* AU was independent before it joined SE; not sure about SU, maybe just because it's old enough to have slipped through.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is named because Canonical has an ownership stake, so it's eligible to use the Trademark.

Comment: It's also worth referencing the original [Domain Names](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/13/domain-names/) blog post regarding the initial consideration of having custom/unique names for each site on the network - as well as [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/06/26/welcome-to-the-arqade/) about gaming.SE being called "Arqade" and (temporarily) having a custom domain name.